# Redirect URL in Orchard after user login?

Tags: orchardcms

How to redirect the page when user logged in Orchard?

I want to redirect to my own module's page with user's credential.

I tried to add a HTML  action link in Orchard.Core.Shapes/Views/User.cshtml to redirect to my own moudle, but it doesn't work.

it seems the page doesn't refresh in this approach.

What 's the better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

An action link is not going to redirect, it's just going to create a link in the page. It's not quite clear what you are trying to do. If you just want to change the layout, override the template. If you want to take over controller logic, I'd recommend creating the same route, with higher priority, pointing to your own replacement controller.